# @PersistenceContext in Autowired Construcor in Spring

Tags: java, spring

I have a Service which looks like this :

```
@Service
public class MyService {

private final EntityManager entityManager;

private final SomeBean someBean;

@Autowired
public DbServiceImpl(EntityManager entityManager, SomeBean someBean) {
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
    this.someBean = someBean;
}
}
```

I need to annotate the `EntityManager` with `@PersistenceContext`. How can I do that, while keeping the `@Autowired` constructor ?
So the question is, can I annotate the constructor parameter `entityManager` separately, while keeping the `@Autowired` annotation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem before and unfortunately I don't think that you can inject the EntityManager in the constructor using the annotation `@Autowired`. See this ticket:

https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-10443

Comment: Unfortunately if you want to use Spring DI and annotations injection the only solution that you have is using the annotation @PersistenceContext on the filed EntityManager.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you need to have the EntityManager in the constructor. Actually, you cannot do it.
You can check a detailed solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33074547/spring-boot-configure-entitymanager).