# Spring boot EntityManager injection

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

In Java SE I can create EntityManager instance via EntityManagerFactory and I can create as many as I want. 
In Spring boot I inject EntityManager via @PersistenceContext.
How does it work?
Does it mean in is injected only one time only? and what if I close it (like closing a session in hibernate?) how can I re-inject it? (like opening new session or creating new entityManager instance)

Comment: check this related question and it's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33074547/11065438

Comment: You may want to read about Spring Boot https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jpa-and-spring-data