# Fetch Data from Database using JPA and Spring Boot without entity or POJO class?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have created a config table in MS SQL Db. I want to fetch all the details of config table. But I don't want to create a POJO class for that. How can I fetch the detail using JPA 2.2 and spring boot in this scenario?

I looked for something on google and I found [this](https://www.journaldev.com/17379/jpa-entitymanager-hibernate). Which Uses Hibernate `EntityManager`. But I am wondering is this the best way to do this. Already I have given connection detail in `application.properties` file. Do I need to give the details again in `persistence.xml` file.

Comment: Look at the hibernate [dynamic model](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#dynamic-model)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution for this. What I did, create entity manager using below annotation:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;
```

and inside any method just call like this:

`List<Object[]> category = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM CATEGORY" ).getResultList();`

Got hint from this answer [[Spring boot - configure EntityManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33074547/spring-boot-configure-entitymanager) ]